# Activity returns wrong requestCode

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 4 Activities `A -> B-> C -> D`

from Activity `D`  I want to go back to `B`

here is the code

```
manifest:
<activity android:name=".GetAttendance" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

.

```
Activity D
Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewGuest.this, GetAttendance.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("guest", temp);// temp is an object
                    setResult(600, intent);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

on Activity `B`, I am calling:

```
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("requestCode:"+requestCode+"  resultCode:"+resultCode);
}
```

But I am getting the `requestCode` equals to **1000** where it I am sending it **600**

However, when Activity `B` calls `C` and before going to `D` I'm setting requestcode to 1000 `startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);`

any suggestion?

Comment: maybe this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225038/wrong-requestcode-returned-onactivityresult-from-another-activity/27225365

Comment: Thanks @amir133, I tried it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a requestCode of 1000, which can be seen from your `startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);` statement

You were expecting a 600, but the call to `setResult(600, intent);` is setting the result code to 600

This is different because you are expecting for a **request code**, whereas the 600 value is for **result code**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)

Comment: OK, the resultCode returns as **0**

Comment: A result code of 0 means cancelled, or you pressed back button or you did not set a a resultvalue. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED

Comment: Even when I return back from C to B I get reultCode=0

Comment: call setResult() , then call finish()  not startactivity. Finish() will trigger the onActivityResult() callback of the previous screen

Comment: I am calling setResult(600, intent). and using startActivity() because finish() will return to the previous one `C` while I need to go to `B`

Comment: Thanks for the try though

Comment: try calling finish() from D then finish() from C, inside the onresultactivity. chaining the requestcodes and passing resultcodes from D to C  until C to B.

Comment: I guess it is one way to do it but it is not the optimal one. Thank you